# how to add two Textfield in row. im add to this code but give a error

Tags: flutter

```
 Container(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(child: TextField()),
                Container(child: TextField()),
              ],
            ),
          )
```

this code is not working on two Textfield in row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code and wrap your TextField inside [`Expanded`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) Widget:

```
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      const SizedBox(
        width: 10,
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Result-> [image]

Comment: ok its helpfull.

Comment: @renilsavani please try to mark my answer if its helpful to you